# Update NuGet package to last version after build in VSTS

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

first of all, excuse me for my English.

In VSTS (visual studio team services), I want to activate automatic compilation for my application. Before I bought the services, I wanted to know if my case would work.

I have a project A that has a dependency on project B. Project B will create a NuGet package each time a commit to master is uploaded.

I want you to commit a master commit on project A, VSTS build the project, but before that upgrade the NuGet package dependency from project B to the latest version.

Would that be possible? Or do I have to do Project Committee b, update the reference in Project A, and then upload Project A?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, check out the PackageReference tag in your project.  You use this directly within your project, not a separate packages.config file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

You can use a Floating reference that will trigger the latest version automatically being consumed, e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: We are using VS2015, but upgrade to 2017 is possible. Looks like it's working, although we want to run more tests.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is that you can call [nuget update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update) command to update the packages to the latest version before Visual Studio Build task in the build.

Comment: Our NuGet packages we want you to upgrade to the latest version, but we don't want to upgrade external packages. thanks.

Comment: You can specify Source or package IDs option .