# PackageReference to project in the same Solution/git repository

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, project-reference, github-ci

At the moment I'm trying to setup a solution with a implementations class library and an abstractions project. I want to have both packages on nuget.org.

Normally when you're just using ProjectReferences, you'd only have to point to the csproj:

Random.Abstractions:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>Abstractions for the Randomizer</Description>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>Apache-2.0</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <Company>MyCompany</Company>
    <Authors>Pieterjan De Clippel</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Random

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Random.Abstractions\Random.Abstractions.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But off course when you build a nuget package, you don't want the **Random.Abstractions.dll** to be inside the **Random** nuget package, but the **Random** package to depend on the **Random.Abstractions** package. But since this package doesn't exist yet, you can't build it yet.

Microsoft is able to solve this problem [like this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.csproj#L24):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So this is neither a `ProjectReference` nor a `PackageReference`, which is why they are able to:

1. build and test the solution locally (so there they'd be acting as `ProjectReferences`)
2. push the code to GitHub and let the GitHub Actions create and publish the new version of the packages, while they depend on each other (so there they'd be acting as `PackageReferences`)

I've tried doing the same in my solution, but the project containing the concrete implementations is unable to find the abstractions project:

MyCompany.Random.Abstractions.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>Abstractions for the Randomizer</Description>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>Apache-2.0</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <Company>MyCompany</Company>
    <Authors>John Wick</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

MyCompany.Random.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyCompany.Random.Abstractions" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So no ProjectReference (we don't want the dll to be in this nuget package), no PackageReference (the package is not yet published), but just Reference.
But somehow I'm still getting an error that the Abstractions assembly cannot be found:

[image: Abstractions assembly cannot be found]

I've checked the NuGet.config but there's nothing really special in there.

How can I use the `Reference` tag in a dotnet-based project, in order to reference to code while building/testing locally and reference the new package while building/pushing in a CI pipeline?

[Reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview)

### Update:

@pinkfloydx33, you're right. I can see only one assembly/dll inside the nupkg:

[image: Contents of the nuget package]

### Update 2:

I added the `Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub` package to my project, and after downloading/unzipping the new version of my package I can see the following `nuspec`:

[image: nuspec after adding Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub package]

Where `77b181a24a83e46b4c80376f65bb305bedba1a64` is the commit ID.

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If each project publishes a package and they are project references in source, dotnet pack/nuget pack will actually build the package and translate them to  package references

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I've just read the same response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888070/8941307). So I'm already giving it a shot :-)

Comment: You're right. I can see there's only one dll inside the generated package.

Comment: Yah it's how we build all our shared dlls. We have several projects that all reference each other via Project Reference in some way. During CI we just dotnet pack/push and it's turned into 7 nupkg all with the correct Package References. nuget pack also does this (and for ages had an *explicit* command line option to create packages for referenced assemblies)

Comment: Just a suggestion if you aren't doing it already,. Make sure you include the appropriate version (for your type of git) of Microsoft's SourceLink package. It will at build time tag your packages with the git commit SHA. That in turn gives you A. A direct link to which version of code is represented (preserved in the AssemblyVersionInfo attribute as well as some nupkg metadata) and B. A debugging experience that tells Visual Studio to step-in to the actual source code the package was built with, directly from the repo

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

**Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG'"** in **ProjectReference** and **Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG'"** with **PackageReference**

This works fine for me and depends from configuration flavour.

**Example:**

```
 <ProjectReference Include="..\Company.Project1\Company.Project1.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG'" />
 <PackageReference Include="Company.Project1" Version="1.*"  Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG'"/>

 <ProjectReference Include="..\Company.Project2\Company.Project2.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG'" />
 <PackageReference Include="Company.Project2" Version="1.*"  Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG'"/>
```

Comment: The comments from @pinkfloydx33 state that during packaging, the `ProjectReference`s are automatically being converted to `PackageReference`s, so you actually only have to make sure the project is packable