# Generating NuGet package from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

So I have a solution with 6 projects, 2 for testing, one for API and 3 Class libs (BL, Common and Integration), I want to use some BL services inside other solution, I'm trying to create a NuGet package out of the BL project but I'm note sure what to do with the Common and the Integration project, because the BL project references them.
So my question is should I create 3 separate NuGet packages (BL, Common and Integration) or will the BL be enough?

Comment: When the other projects have `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` and a `PackageId`, the build will replace the ProjectReferences with PackageReferences, or at least that's what happens in a Github build pipeline

Comment: [This question already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893338/packagereference-to-project-in-the-same-solution-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the other class libs (referenced directly or indirectly through BL) then you need to publish those nuget packages.

Comment: So i create 3 nugets and in BL i reference the other two nugets